# Getting "A hard disk may be failing" on startup

Tags: gnome, hard-disk

[image: Error]

I keep getting this error message each time I start GNOME, even though I created a new partition table on this drive, I formatted all the partitions, and created them again, and this just won't go away.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

I ran badblocks, and this is what I got

> badblocks -svw /dev/sdb
>   Checking for bad blocks in read-write mode
>   From block 0 to 80042206
>   Testing with pattern 0xaa: done
>   Reading and comparing: done
>   Testing with pattern 0x55: done
>   Reading and comparing: done
>   Testing with pattern 0xff: done
>   Reading and comparing: done
>   Testing with pattern 0x00: done
>   Reading and comparing: done
>   Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found

Comment: What happens when you click the icon?

Comment: @Gilles It says that the disk has too many bad sectors, I click on it, the message disappears, but the icon just stays there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `System->Administration->Disk Utility`, select your hard drive from the list on the left and then click `SMART Data` on the right. You will get a report about your disk status and errors.

You may continue by clicking the `Run Self-test` button and start an `Extensive` self-test. Wait until it's finished and read the final report. Running `badblocks` or `e2fsck -c` (from your live rescue disk) on your filesystems will mark bad clusters so they won't be used by the OS. But if error counters keep rising by time, your disk needs replacement asap. You should already have a backup.

Unfortunately, current inexpensive disks are as reliable as floppy disks were a decade ago. Though, being inexpensive makes raid1 (mirror) a considerable option for desktop systems too.

**EDIT**

I thought *Disk Utility* was installed by default in Ubuntu. The package's name is `gnome-disk-utility`, so one way to install it is `sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility`. Get the same functionality in command line with `smartctl` from `smartmontools` package.

**EDIT2**

I forgot that there was a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libatasmart/+bug/413673) with `gnome-disk-utility` reporting false warnings. I don't know if it's fixed yet, I never experienced it myself. More info in dealing with disk problems [here](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/badblockhowto.html).

Comment: I don't have Disk Utility, I only have disk usage analyzer, I don't think it's what you're referring to, I'll try one of those two commands you've mentioned, though.

Comment: @Mahmoud Hossam, updated my answer.

Comment: @forcefsck I use mandriva.

Comment: @Mahmoud Hossam, they all look alike these days :) . Package names are more or less the same in most distros. Use the distro's package manager to install it.

Comment: @forcefsck hmm...that's interesting, gnome-disk-utility is already installed, yet there's no program with this name, even when I'm root, however, I ran badblocks and it's checking the device right now.

Comment: @Mahmoud Hossam, makes sense since it's the same applet that gives you the warning. To start the gui from command prompt run `palimpsest`. Another nice gui for SMART is `gsmartcontrol`.

Comment: @forcefsck updated the question.

Comment: @Mahmoud Hossam, badblocks is not the only indication of failing disks. Check my last edit and the added links for more info.

Comment: @forcefsck I booted my computer today, and the problem just went away all by itself, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your hard drive?

Did you click the icon for more information?  It sounds like your drive's [S.M.A.R.T.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) firmware is reporting an imminent hardware failure.  Keep those backups up to date.

Comment: That's a secondary hard drive that I don't use very often, I don't have any problems with it if it fails, is there a way to get rid of this notification while keeping it for now?